# Getting an infinite loop while trying to remove from a queue

Tags: java

I'm modeling a fastfood drive-through using a priority queue of Event objects (yep, homework). There are three stations, an order, payment and collection station, each with their own queues. I'm having an issue removing an item from the collection station (the last station visited by a Customer). When the collection queue fills up, the simulation begins to loop indefinitely and the timer no longer increments. I assume it's because of this line:

```
public void processFoodCollection(Customer c, Event e) {
   collection.remove(c);//this is the issue I believe
   collection.setServerStatus(false);
```

However, if I attempt to use my standard remove() method (which just calls queue.poll() in the station class), it returns null. I have no idea why this would happen after having just added to the queue, it's given me zero problems any other time I've used it at the other stations (and I just copy-pasted the methods for each station class, they're all identical). I'd really appreciate any help on identifying what is causing this loop, or, if it is the remove(c), how I can fix this.

Here's my Restaurant class (contains the simulation, lazy I know), but hopefully it's not necessary to look at since my documentation isn't complete yet: http://pastebin.com/cHj3xqJN[1]

Here's the method in particular I'm having issue with (collection is a CollectionStation var composed of a queue field, the remove(Customer c) and remove() methods are just for access to the queue methods):

```
public void processFoodCollection(Customer c, Event e) {
   collection.remove(c);//Customer c should be head of queue
   collection.setServerStatus(false);//cashier not helping anyone
   if (collection.getQueueSize() < 2) {
      //process event if room available in collection queue
      collection.add(payment.remove());//remove customer from payment queue, add to collection queue
      payment.setServerStatus(false);
      if (!collection.getServerStatus())
          createFinishCollection(collection.peek());//creates event to be processed in the future
      //generate new finish payment event for new head of payment queue
      if (payment.getQueueSize()>0) {
          double b = this.exponentialPay.next();//minutes until finished paying
          while (b == 0.0) {
              b = this.exponentialPay.next();//ensure return > 0.0
          }
          createFinishPayment(b, payment.peek());
      }
      //check if head of order queue can move up
      if (order.getQueueSize() > 0) {
          if (order.peek().getTimeFinished() == this.clockTime && order.getServerStatus()) {
              processFinishOrder(order.peek(), eventList.peek());
          } else if (!order.getServerStatus()) {
              double timeToOrder = (order.peek().getOrderSize() * this.timeToOrderItem);
              createFinishOrder(timeToOrder, order.peek());
          }
      }
  }
}//end method processFoodCollection
```

If I try to use the remove() method, I get a null pointer exception at:

```
Event newE = new Event(Events.FINISHFOODCOLLECTION, this.clockTime + (c.getOrderSize() * this.timeToProcessItem), c);
```

from the null customer object (c). This traces back to the createFinishCollection() method call in the above code. So this is how I know I get a null from calling remove, but I don't understand why my queue would say it's empty when I just added to it. Is there some trick to look out for when indirectly removing data structure elements?

Here's the remove method I'm calling (in the CollectionStation class):

```
/**
 * Removes and returns object at front of queue.
 * @return 
 */
public Customer remove() {
    return customerQueue.poll();
}//end method remove
```

I'm honestly pretty stumped why this wouldn't work. Any guidance would be appreciated (not looking for answers, just help).

Comment: What is the purpose of the `collection` queue?

Comment: @vandale It holds up to two customers in the "line" to collect their food. Each station has its own queue (the order queue is infinite, the payment can hold up to three and the collecton up to two).

Comment: I would recommend using a debugger to step through the method and ensure that all your fields are in a valid state.

Comment: @vandale Okay, thanks. I've never used one before so I guess it'll be a learning experience!

Comment: Using poll() should be avoided. If you have queues, threads should process them, and they simply block at the receiving end (as you do before a counter). It *seems* to me (I could be wrong) that you are trying to implement this model with its timing dependencies and interactions between stations and queueing strategies according to the burger order in a sequential program, which is almost impossible to do. If this is homework, it's either for an advanced ComSci lecture, or you are trying to implement a more sophisticated solution than is actually required.

Comment: @laune I'm pretty sure my professor took this from an advanced course but he said we'd talk about it in class and then we never did. I've talked to him extensively about just how to build this project, since the design document is terribly uninformative, and this is how he said I should build it, using a priority queue of events (arrivals, finish order, finish paying, finish collecting food) that point to customer objects. This is tricky because he said not to have pointers to events for the customers, but I may have to break down and do that just to get it submitted on time.

Comment: @laune Also, I don't know anything about threads, this is for a second course in the Intro to CompSci freshman sequence. So I appreciate your advice, but I'm afraid it's lost on me at the moment.

Comment: @Ben "2nd course:" That's what I thought. - Nevertheless, that advice of the *single* queue of all events is the one approach that avoids confusion. Consider computed or fabricated (for the simulation) events at points in time and a *single* queue ordered on time. You'll just need one sequential processor to handle one event after the other. - If the queue is empty, the simulation stops, as all customer arrivals would have to be entered up front. Events scheduled due to orders at the second or third station will be inserted with later times.

Comment: @laune Right, and that's how I've built my simulation. My problem comes in trying to remove customers from the collection queue when they've completed their last event. They just don't leave that final queue (even though their associated event has left the priority queue).

Comment: Hmm, then you'll have to show all of the CollectionStation class, at least *every* method accessing customerQueue and the sequences of these methods' calls, according to the use cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why am I stuck in an infinite loop after invoking poll() or remove() on a priority queue? Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664409/why-am-i-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-after-invoking-poll-or-remove-on-a-priori)