# why am I stuck in an infinite loop after invoking poll() or remove() on a priority queue? Java

Tags: java

I get stuck in an infinite for loop if I invoke the `remove()` or `poll()` on the priority queue below.

I am trying to print out all the elements in there. So every time I print out the last attribute of the Process elements, I call `remove()` or `poll()` on it. And I get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public class SPN {

    private int CPU_Burst_Cycles = 0;
    PriorityQueue<Process> prq;
    PriorityQueue<Process> ready_queue;
    Process current;

    public SPN(PriorityQueue<Process> prqPass) {

        //Priority Queue of the processes
        prq = prqPass;

        System.out.println(prq.size());
        for(int i = 0; i<prq.size(); i++) {

            //THIS IS WHERE I GET IN TROUBLE
            System.out.println(prq.peek().getName() + "'s rem time: " + prq.remove().getRemTime());

            System.out.println("Actual size: " + prq.size());

        }
.
.
.
.
}
```

Process class:

```
public class Process {

    private String name;
    private int arrive_time= 0;
    private int burst_time = 0;
    private int remain_time = 0;

    public Process (String name, int arr_time, int bur_time) {

        this.arrive_time = arr_time;
        this.burst_time = bur_time;
        this.remain_time = burst_time;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getArrTime() {return arrive_time;}
    public int getBurTime() {return burst_time;}
    public int getRemTime() {return remain_time;}
    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void decRemTime() {this.remain_time--;}
}
```

Then in a third class I create a SPN instance and I pass it a priority queue.
If I just do a `peek()` it works fine.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

    public class Test {

        //Priority READY_QUEUE for the accessed processes
        public static PriorityQueue<Process> prq = new PriorityQueue<Process>(5, new Comparator<Process> () {

            @Override
            public int compare(Process p1, Process p2) {
                return p1.getArrTime() - p2.getArrTime();
            }
        });

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line;

            try {
                br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Veni\\Desktop\\test\\test.txt\\"));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
                System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage() + "File not found");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] params = line.split(" ");
                prq.add(new Process(params[0], Integer.parseInt(params[1]), Integer.parseInt(params[2]) ));
            }       
            SPN spn = new SPN(prq);
            spn.SPN_ALG();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Iterator.remove()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) says (in part)

> This method can be called only once per call to [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--). The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

```
public SPN(PriorityQueue<Process> prq) {
    System.out.println(prq.size());
    Iterator<Process> iter = prq.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Process p = iter.next();
        System.out.println(p.getName() + "'s rem time: "
                + p.getRemTime());
        iter.remove();
        System.out.println("Actual size: " + prq.size());
    }
}
```